# Bi-Directional CSS Transitions

Tags: html, google-chrome, css-transitions

I'm using vendor prefixed css transitions, based on [this demo](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/flexbox/index.html), which seems to only be working in Chrome 22+ at the moment. I'm trying to turn the buttons (Home, Contact, About) into drop-down menus on hover. I want to avoid using javascript and see if I can do it all with CSS.

It fades in if I have the z-index set to a low number (-999) and on hover change it to a high number (999), and change the opacity from 0 to 1 using a transition.

```
nav > div div {
    z-index: -999;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
nav > div:hover div {
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

See the Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CsC9y/).

The problem is it won't fade back out. If I change the transition to also delay the z-index from changing then it will fade out, but not in (`-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, z-index 0 linear 1s`). Modifications to the Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CsC9y/1/).

Essentially what's going on is the opacity fading works fine, but z-index moves too quickly in either one direction or the other. If I don't use z-index at all, then it will open the menu when I'm hovering *below* the "Hover Me" button instead of *on* it. [Here's another Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CsC9y/2/) showing that scenario.

Is there a way to have one transition for going from point A to point B, and another transition for going from point B to point A? I've played around with putting a separate transition on the `:hover` element but as far as I can tell it just overrides the first one (as if there is no transition from "not hovering" to "hovering").

TL;DR: Is there a way to modify [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CsC9y/), [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CsC9y/1/), or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CsC9y/2/) to make a smooth transition when hovering on (not just near) the "Hover Me" button (without using javascript)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CsC9y/3/). Not sure if it does what you want, but I changed the following...

**CSS**

```
nav > div > div {
  z-index: -999;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, z-index 0 linear 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, z-index 0 linear 1s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, z-index 0 linear 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, z-index 0 linear 1s;
}
nav > div:hover > div {
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, z-index 0 linear 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, z-index 0 linear 0;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, z-index 0 linear 0;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, z-index 0 linear 0;
}
```

I've added transitions to the hover state as well, but with a delay of 0.

Comment: Yup that's exactly what I was going for. I was sure I'd tried something like that. Thanks!